# Repeating fields format in Python

Tags: python, string, binary, format, repeat

I'm converting a custom instrument binary data into a CSV file.
There're 100+ fields with float, int and texts.
I'm using bitstruct for it.

```
    with open('instrument.dat','rb') as f:
        with open('instrument.csv','w') as w:
           header_format = 'u32u8u32t8192'
           header_size = calcsize_in_bytes(header_format)
           body_format = 'u4u4u1u1u1u1u4u16t96f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32s16s16f32f32u16u16f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f3232f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32s16s16f32f32u16u16f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32<'
           body_size = calcsize_in_bytes(body_format)

           ver,instrument,date,comment = unpack(header_format, f.read(header_size))
           w.write('{},{},{},{}\n'.format(ver,instrument,date,comment))
           while True:
               field1,...,fieldn = unpack(body_format,f.read(body_size))
```

My question is how to write body part in CSV?
I wouldn't wanna write something cumbersome like:

`w.write("{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}...{}\n".format(field1, field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,fiel8,...,fieldN))`

Is there any short and smart way to this?

Thanks in advance.

More details:

There are 100+ fields with different values in binary.
Format is like that:

```
u4u4u1u1u1u1u4u16t96f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32s16s16f32f32u16u16f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f3232f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32s16s16f32f32u16u16f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32<
```

`u` is unsigned `int`, `f` is `float`, `s` is `text` are all in bits

All I want is comma-separated values so I can import them into different programs.

```
Header1,Header2,Header3,…,Header100
Value1,value2,value3,…,value100
...
Value1,value2,value3,...,value100
```

Comment: Quick answer: ```brackets = "{}" * len(variables); fields = brackets.format(*variables)```

Comment: That one worked! Anyway to shorten fields? Maybe put them in an array and cycle through? Not sure however how to unpack that into array.

Comment: If you put some example about given input and the expected output, maybe I can be more helpful.

Comment: put more details in the post, hope it helps

Comment: I'd need to know unpack and calcsize_in_bytes functions.

Comment: Maybe you can replace last line (```field1,...,fieldn = unpack(body_format,f.read(body_size))```) with something like ```variables = unpack(body_format,f.read(body_size)); brackets = "{}" * len(variables); w.write(brackets.format(*variables))``` [where ; is for a new line]. If you want another result, please specify more details ;)

Comment: Great! It did work! I'm new to python. Thank you!

Comment: Please accept the solution to close this question. I put it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution, based on above comments.

```py
    with open('instrument.dat','rb') as f:
        with open('instrument.csv','w') as w:
           header_format = 'u32u8u32t8192'
           header_size = calcsize_in_bytes(header_format)
           body_format = 'u4u4u1u1u1u1u4u16t96f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32s16s16f32f32u16u16f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f3232f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32s16s16f32f32u16u16f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32f32<'
           body_size = calcsize_in_bytes(body_format)

           ver,instrument,date,comment = unpack(header_format, f.read(header_size))
           w.write('{},{},{},{}\n'.format(ver,instrument,date,comment))
           while True:
               variables = unpack(body_format,f.read(body_size))
               brackets = "{}," * len(variables)
               brackets = brackes.rstrip(',') + "\n"
               w.write(brakets.format(*variables))
```